# Changing data in OpenApi info block

Tags: gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to change my OpenApi info block properties.

More specifically I'm trying to change the value of the version tag in my OpenApi programmatically.
For example every new build I want a new version number.

I have tried using placeholders and giving them values in the build.gradle but haven't got it working.

openapi:

```
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: Dummy Bookshop
  summary: A fictitious API demonstrating the OpenAPI Specification's features
  version: ${apiVersion}
  description: A fictius description.
  termsOfService: https://www.dummy-book.shop/tos
  contact:
    name: Bookshop Support team
    url: https://www.dummy-book.shop/support
    email: support@dummy-book.shop
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    identifier: Apache-2.0
paths: {}
```

build.gradle:

```
ext {
    apiVersion = '1.0.1'
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this working or is there a plugin that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script in your build.gradle to replace the version with the gradle version.  This is easily done using the groovy YamlSlurper.

```
task updateYaml() {
    def fileDir = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/static/"
    def fileName = "myOpenApi.yml"
    def reader = new FileReader(fileDir + fileName)
    def slurper = new YamlSlurper()
    def builder = new YamlBuilder()
    builder slurper.parse(reader)
    builder.content.info.version = project.version


    doLast {
        File newOASFile = new File(fileDir, "finalSpec.yml")
        newOASFile.write(builder.toString())
    }
}
```

Once you have the task working, set your dependencies properly.  This assumes that your generation task is called generateMyOpenApi

```
generateMyOpenApi.dependsOn updateYaml
processResources.dependsOn generateMyOpenApi
```